# Using keyboard in Microsoft Band app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-band

Ok, I'm developing app for Microsoft Band and I cannot find in Documentation about how to add Keyboard ability like in Messaging app, when you can reply. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The Band SDK does not expose the keyboard to third-party applications.

Comment: What you are trying to do? Why not use Cortana? Create an mobile application with Cortana, and add some commands, on Microsoft Band you command your application with Cortana.